# Hierarchic vs hierarchical

Tags: adjectives, suffixes

I want to ask whether a certain abstract structure has to have children of the same kind, possibly nested an infinite number of times. The closest example would be a genealogy tree where each node has scalar properties, like first name or gender, and also successors, each having scalar properties and successors, and so on. So, should I ask, "should this structure be hierarchic" or "should this structure be hierarchical"? What's the difference between the two?

Comment: Unlike, say, ***electric / electrical***, which are both very common, and have thus gradually acquired different connotations and usages, I don't think there's really any generally-recognized distinction between ***hierarchic*** and ***hierarchical***. But the latter is [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Hierarchic%2CHierarchical&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHierarchic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHierarchical%3B%2Cc0), so I suggest you use it.

Comment: See also at EL&U: *[“Hierarchical” vs. “hierarchic”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140602)*

Comment: I found this gem on wikidiff.com: "... the difference between hierarchic and hierarchical is that hierarchic is hierarchal while hierarchical is pertaining to a hierarchy". Got that? Good.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to revolve around a computer science data structure problem of whether nested objects are hierarchical.

They are not.

However, they can sometimes be transformed into a tree-like structure and be *hierarchical*.

You should use *hierarchical* since it is part of the technical terminology for computers.

> hierarchical data structures
>   hierarchical database
>   hierarchical hashing
>   hierarchical hidden Markov models
>   hierarchical k-means tree
>   hierarchical clustering

The only phrase I've come across using hierarchic is *hierarchic escalation* which means *pushing things up the chain of command*.